# SQL - Count month difference in non-consecutive date period

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to extract how many months of membership a member gets up to date. As the picture shows, this member got four years of subscription since 2018. However, she stopped the subscription for a year ending in 2019. And then, restart the membership in 2020 again.

Each membership lasts for 12 months. if we look at the last membership starting from 2022-05-08, it will end up on 2023-05-08. However, I only want to get the total month count up to date(getdate - 2022-09-14).

Please advise how I could approach this matter. Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATJVD.jpg)

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data, please paste them in as text

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you were planning to apply `sum(monthcount)`, you could wrap the `monthcount` within a CASE statement to checks if the `vip_end` is greater than today's date:

```
sum(case when vip_end > getdate() then ... else monthcount end)
```

What you do within that `...` depends on whether you wanted to just count the different number of months within the date range (e.g. 31st Jan -> 01st Feb is counted as a whole month because it just considers Jan -> Feb):

```
datediff(month, datecreated, getdate())
```

or perhaps calculate the number of months based on the average days in a month:

```
datediff(day, datecreated, getdate())*12.0/365.25
```

or maybe something else... it really depends on what level of detail you want to achieve.